# VM Instances Language Google Cloud Platform

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-platform, platform, iaas

This might be an ulta noob question but I have searched a lot about it and have no answers yet.

So, when I create an VM Instance on Google Cloud Platform, the language of the Instance is always "English". Is there any way I could change the language of the Instance when creating it?

What I haved researched is that the Regions and Zones only defines where you what the instance to be stored and there are commands that worked for me changing the language, here they are:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-es
sudo apt-get install language-pack-es-base
sudo apt-get install language-support-es
sudo apt-get install aspell-es
sudo apt-get install myspell-es
sudo apt-get install manpages-es
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you creating VM it uses predifined OS image. You can choose one or another, but all of them will be with englesh language by default.

You can change the language of the OS as you shown, or you can create your custom OS image that will come with predefined by you default language.